# Can I set gulp flags as default?

Tags: gulp

I want to set the flag `--silent`as default in my gulp tasks. Ist this possible?

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/CLI.md#flags

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way if you are running a shell is to use alias:

alias gulp 'gulp --silent' (check the specific syntax for you shell type).

If you'd like to take it a step further, in your project go into:

node_modules/gulp/bin

and edit gulp.js

You'd see there the following lines:

```
var shouldLog = !argv.silent && !simpleTasksFlag;

if (!shouldLog) {
  gutil.log = function(){};
}
```

If you want to categorically disable logging, just change it to:

```
var shouldLog = false;
```

If you want to disable it on a per task basis, you can do it by manipulating gulp-util's (gutil in this code) log method:

```
gulp.task('mySilentTask', function(){
    gutil.log = function(){}; // make sure you obtain gutil properly
    // task logic here
});
```

Comment: an interesting exploration of Gulp's internals w/o a doubt. but isn't it pretty shady to go around editing core package files? def. not best-practice, altho... in this context Gulp's lack of a programatic interface for managing flags may make it the _only_ answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can set default flags for Gulp by adding a configuration file `.gulp.json` next to the gulpfile:

```
{
    "flags": {
        "silent": true
    }
}
```

See `gulp-cli` documentation for configuration for more details: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli#configuration